# Makefile.am retrieve variable of other Makefile.am

Tags: variables, automake, subdirectory

I have a directory structure like

```
 Makefile.am
 src/foo/Makefile.am
 src/foo/bar/Makefile.am
```

for now me want to retrieve in `Makefile.am` variables defined in

```
 src/foo/Makefile.am and src/foo/bar/Makefile.am
```

I want to build application in top directory how can I achieve that?
For now me just gets 8 Byte sized libraries and failure on program.

Comment: Those values should be substituted in each `Makefile.am` if you need them, when using `AC_CONFIG_FILES` and `AC_OUTPUT` at the end of the configure script. You can't really use the [autotools](https://autotools.io/index.html) in a hit-and-miss way.

Comment: Hi, me getting following error even gsequencer_SOURCES was empty initialized:
error: gsequencer_SOURCES must be set with '=' before using '+='

Comment: For now me did SUBDIRS and include after initiliazation but still same behaviour as previously mentioned

Comment: the project is http://ags.sf.net

Comment: I'm sorry - I simply can't spend hours looking carefully at ISO images, or a huge `ags` codebase that I don't understand. I'm not even entirely sure I'm looking at the right code. Also, your additional comments don't help me. My advice is to learn autotools properly, or cmake. Don't try to skip over things, because they will always help you with other projects and build systems in the future. Your alternative is to bring someone on board to manage code quality / testing / building, leaving you to concentrate on the core that you understand best. Good luck.

Comment: What me wanted is probably something like recursive automake what is considered as bad-practice as me understand it